# Remove custom tags from web service response

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have created a simple web service using Java and axis 2. The output i am getting is as follows,

Input-
**http://localhost:8088/Newwww/services/NewFile/newFile?s=New%20data3**

Output-

```
<ns:newFileResponse xmlns:ns="http://Services.tcs.com">
- <ns:return>
- <TestData>
  <testData1>New data1</testData1> 
  <testData2>New data2</testData2> 
  <testData3>New data3</testData3> 
  </TestData>
  </ns:return>
  </ns:newFileResponse>
```

How can i remove the tags starting with ns:
In short i want the response to be only

```
<TestData>
  <testData1>New data1</testData1> 
  <testData2>New data2</testData2> 
  <testData3>New data3</testData3> 
  </TestData>
```

My WSDL file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://Services.tcs.com" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://Services.tcs.com">
  <wsdl:documentation>Please Type your service description here</wsdl:documentation> 
- <wsdl:types>
- <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://Services.tcs.com">
- <xs:element name="newFile">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="s" nillable="true" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
- <xs:element name="newFileResponse">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
- <wsdl:message name="newFileRequest">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:newFile" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:message name="newFileResponse">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:newFileResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
- <wsdl:portType name="NewFilePortType">
- <wsdl:operation name="newFile">
  <wsdl:input message="ns:newFileRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:newFile" /> 
  <wsdl:output message="ns:newFileResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:newFileResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
- <wsdl:binding name="NewFileSoap11Binding" type="ns:NewFilePortType">
  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:operation name="newFile">
  <soap:operation soapAction="urn:newFile" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
- <wsdl:binding name="NewFileSoap12Binding" type="ns:NewFilePortType">
  <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:operation name="newFile">
  <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:newFile" style="document" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <soap12:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <soap12:body use="literal" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
- <wsdl:binding name="NewFileHttpBinding" type="ns:NewFilePortType">
  <http:binding verb="POST" /> 
- <wsdl:operation name="newFile">
  <http:operation location="NewFile/newFile" /> 
- <wsdl:input>
  <mime:content type="text/xml" part="newFile" /> 
  </wsdl:input>
- <wsdl:output>
  <mime:content type="text/xml" part="newFile" /> 
  </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
- <wsdl:service name="NewFile">
- <wsdl:port name="NewFileHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:NewFileSoap11Binding">
  <soap:address location="http://localhost:8088/Newwww/services/NewFile.NewFileHttpSoap11Endpoint/" /> 
  </wsdl:port>
- <wsdl:port name="NewFileHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:NewFileSoap12Binding">
  <soap12:address location="http://localhost:8088/Newwww/services/NewFile.NewFileHttpSoap12Endpoint/" /> 
  </wsdl:port>
- <wsdl:port name="NewFileHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:NewFileHttpBinding">
  <http:address location="http://localhost:8088/Newwww/services/NewFile.NewFileHttpEndpoint/" /> 
  </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
  </wsdl:definitions>
```

Thanks..

Comment: Please post your definition file (WSDL) here as well. The xml you are getting looks like your response dataset is wrapped with the operation body tags (newFileResponse)

Comment: I have posted it.. Can u pls help me out....

Comment: Its expanded in the posted WSDL..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this. There are two options.

1. Use the contract first approach[1].

There you need to modify the generated wsdl for suite for you or create a new one and generate the code for that using wsdl2java tool and deploy the service.

1. Use an ESB to do the transformation of the response.

Here you can create a proxy service in the ESB and do any transformation of the response at the out sequence[2].

[1] http://wso2.org/library/2873
[2] http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.0/docs/samples/message_mediation_samples.html#Sample8

Answer (score 1):

Your WSDL reveals your use of one of the worst antipatterns with web services: Use of anyType.
Your interface should define what kind of data is sent and accepted by other part - using anyType forces both sides of the interface to know the internals of the other side.

```
 <xs:element name="newFileResponse">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType" /> 
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

And since you are defining "newFileResponse" (element) as the message part for "newFileResponse" (message), you will of course receive the newFileResponse element as the contents.

First of all: Get rid of anyType, define the testdate element in your interface.

Second: Rename your elements and messages so that they do not have same names - this is to improve the readability.

Third: Use something like the following for your messages

```
<wsdl:message name="newFileResponse">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:TestData" /> 
</wsdl:message>
```

By defining the TestData as your message part instead of the anyType-eating newFileResponse-element, you get rid of the obfuscating wrapper element and get to use the TestData type directly.